# Linux VM not accessible on local network

Tags: linux, windows, networking, virtual-machines

I have a Linux VM in Hyper-V that's only accessible from outside the local network. SSH and HTTP and what not works just fine when port forwarded, but on the local network, it rejects everything, including pings, even from the host machine (Win 10 Pro). I can monitor the network traffic to and from the VM in Wireshark, but that's about it.

Things that might be worth noting:

- I'm using a virtual switch, so the VM has a separate local IP address from the host
- The host also seems to reject pings, but responds to HTTP
- The VM can't find any local devices, including the router